# Excel matching and comparing

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So this seems a bit perplexing to me being that I'm new to Excel.

I have one-to-many relationship with SKU and Part#.

I want to see if each parts' price is equal to each other, but only if they share the same SKU #.

And, if they are not the same price, to return a result of essentially, "different price".

```
SKU#           Part#    Price 
1000-002-581   56465    12800
1000-002-581   800335   13300
1000-002-582   56455    12800
1000-002-582   800325   13300
1000-002-584   56445    12800
1000-002-584   800315   13300
```

Above is the results I currently have.

i.e. `SKU 1000-002-581` has `Part #: 56465 and 800335`.  And the Price for each part is different `(12800 vs 13300)`.  I want to retrieve a message because this is different.

At the end of the day, I would only want to display the lines with part price differences to each associated SKU.

Any thoughts on which collective functions would work?

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to the table with the formula

```
=IF(SUMIF(A:A,A2,C:C)/COUNTIF(A:A,A2)<>C2,"different","")
```

[image]

Turn on Autofilter and filter by the last column.